# Do Improved Initiative & Superior Initiative stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, initiative

Does Improved Initiative (+4 on initiative checks) stacks with Superior Initiative (+8 on initiative checks)? Is it possible (if it's a good idea) to retrain Improved Initiative to Superior on epic tier?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Improved Initiative and Superior Initiative do *not* stack.**

Both feats give a *feat* bonus to initiative, and bonuses of the same type do not stack; therefore, Improved Initiative & Superior Initiative do not stack.

It *is* possible to retrain Improved Initiative for Superior Initiative once you reach epic tier (and it's a good idea to do so, since you're effectively getting +4 init for the price of a retrain), since the only requirement for Superior Initiative is that you be in the epic tier.

Comment: So when i do this retraining, do i 'loose' one feat slot? What i mean is i basically get +4 initiative in a price of an epic tier feat slot?

Comment: No under character management, its something you can do as you level. Once per level up you can retrain one feat of power.

Comment: To clarify what Joshua said, every time you gain a level, you're allowed to replace 1 feat you have with any feat you *currently* qualify for (as long as the feat you're ditching isn't a pre-requisite for anything else you've taken); alternately, you can instead replace any power you have with a power of the same level or lower.

Comment: You can also switch up skill trainings as well. (All of these retrains are contingent on you not trying to retrain something that is a prereq to something else).